# What counts as a "wired" controller when connecting it to my laptop?

Tags: pc, controllers

I'm trying to connect my 360 controller to my laptop but it won't connect. I have it plugged into the USB slot using the cable that came with a charge kit, and I have the "Xbox 360 controller for Windows" software installed already. So far all that's happened is the controller turns on then proceeds to turn on/connect to my Xbox which is in the basement, two floors below me...

Does this charger cable only charge the controller (it does turn on, so that parts working) or also create a wired connection from the controller to the laptop?

Comment: @ColinD Yeaa, that is pretty much the same thing. Just didn't know what the actual name of my 'charger cable' was, or this probably would've shown up in similar questions before I posted.

Comment: I knew there was a better one.

Answer (score 2):

The usb cable from the 'play and charge kit' only charges the controller. It does not allow you to use the controller as a wired controller.

To connect a wireless xbox 360 controller to a pc you need to use an xbox360 wireless gaming receiver.